# Implement a generic Java method using an O(n^2 ) sort and a comparator

Tags: java, sorting, generics

Implement the following generic Java method using an O(n^2) sort and a comparator:

```
public static <E> void aSort(E[] list, Comparator<? super E> comparator)
```

> > Write test program that creates a list of at least 5 elements of the class type created in problem 3
> >     above, calls the above method to sort the list, then outputs the sorted list via calls to toString.

```
Unsorted: 
A Circle with the radius of: [1]
A Circle with the radius of: [15]
A Circle with the radius of: [10]
A Circle with the radius of: [12]
A Circle with the radius of: [100]
```

**I don't know why it's printing this backwards but it is supposed to sort in ascending order**

```
Sorted: 
A Circle with the radius of: [100]
A Circle with the radius of: [12]
A Circle with the radius of: [10]
A Circle with the radius of: [15]
A Circle with the radius of: [1]
```

**This is what I got so far**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Circle c1 = new Circle();
    Circle c2 = new Circle(15);
    Circle c3 = new Circle(10);
    Circle c4 = new Circle(12);
    Circle c5 = new Circle(100);

    Circle w[] = new Circle[5];
    w[0] = c1;
    w[1] = c2;
    w[2] = c3;
    w[3] = c4;
    w[4] = c5;

    CompareCircle cc = new CompareCircle();
    System.out.println("Unsorted: ");
    for (Circle go : w) {
        System.out.println(go.toString());
    }

    bubbleSort(w, new CompareCircle());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Sorted: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(w[i].toString());

    }
   public static <E> void bubbleSort(E[] list, Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
    boolean needNextPass = true;

    for (int k = 1; k < list.length && needNextPass; k++) {
        // Array may be sorted and next pass not needed
        needNextPass = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length - k; i++) {
            if (comparator.compare(list[i], list[i + 1]) > 0) {
                // Swap list[i] with list[i + 1]
                E temp = list[i];
                list[i] = list[i + 1];
                list[i + 1] = temp;

                needNextPass = true; // Next pass still needed
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

> > This is my Circle class

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Circle implements Serializable {

private int radius = 1;

public Circle() {
}

public Circle(int radius) {
    setRadius(radius);

}

public void setRadius(int v) {
    if (v > 0) {
        this.radius = v;
    }

}

public int getRadius() {
    return this.radius;

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "A Circle with the radius of: [" + radius + "]";
}


}
```

> > This is my CompareCircle class

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class CompareCircle implements Comparator<Circle> {

@Override
public int compare(Circle o1, Circle o2) {
    int radius1 = o1.getRadius();
    int radius2 = o2.getRadius();

    if (radius1 < radius2){
        return radius2;
    }
    if (radius1 == radius2){
        return radius1;
    }
    else
        return radius1;
 }

 }
```

Comment: where is the code of the `bubbleSort`method ?

Comment: You didn't include the most important: the sort implementation

Comment: Your [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Comparator.html) is implemented incorrectly (see the documentation of `Comparator#compare`). Apart from that `bubbleSort` is missing, so there isn't much to tell about why it malfunctions.

Comment: Sorry just added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of `bubbleSort` is perfectly fine. `CircleComparator` on the other hand is seriously malformed. No matter which `Circle`s will be passed it will always return a positive integer. Thus in run `n` the first element will be "bubbled" up to index `list.length - n`, and all remaining elements (index `<= list.length - n`) will be pushed one index down, which in the end results in the list being reversed.

A correct comparison-function would return a negative number if the first value is smaller, a positive number if the second value is smaller, and 0 if the parameters are equal (see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Comparator.html)). E.g.:

```
public class CircleCompare implements Comparator<Circle>
{
    public int compare(Circle c1, Circle c2){
        return Integer.compare(c1.getRadius(), c2.getRadius());
    }
}
```

Or as an alternative way if you prefer doing the logic yourself:

```
public class CircleCompare implements Comparator<Circle>
{
    public int compare(Circle c1, Circle c2){
        return c2.getRadius() - c1.getRadius();
    }
}
```